# Relative file path from index.html to node_modules folder not working

Tags: angular, relative-path, angular-cli

I am having trouble linking to files that are in the node_modules folder (both in link tags and script tags) in my index.html file.  My project is Angular2 based, and I used the Angular CLI to generate the project and its file structure.

The index.html file is in the src folder, which is adjacent to the node_modules folder that contains the files I want to link to.

Currently for the relative path I'm using ../ to go back up a folder but it's not working, as the console is giving me errors for the link tag and both script tags in index.html.

Can someone help me with the correct file paths?  Thanks.

[screenshot of index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZOYa.png)

Comment: Attach the screen shot of browser console.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wZOYa.png

Comment: Try putting them in app.scripts in angular-cli.json instead.

"scripts" : [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]

Comment: Thank you, that worked for the script tags!  But what about the link tag to the file that's also in the node_modules folder? Would that go somewhere else as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's convenient to use the `angular-cli.json` file for including *styles* (`<link>`) and *scripts* (`<script>`) to your `index.html`.

Just use `apps[0].scripts` for *scripts* linking and similarly `apps[0].styles` for *styles*.

Another way is to include your stylesheets directly to the `styles.css/scss/less` file located in your `src/` dir.